# Nginx + PHP-FPM multiple connections from single client

Tags: php, nginx

Here's the problem I'm having.

I have my development machine set up with Nginx and PHP-FPM.  On the whole it works fine, except when I have a long-running process that imports lots of very big files into a database.  Now before you start thinking this is another "gateway timeout" issue, it's not (sorta).

The long running process itself is working fine.  That process actually sends back unbuffered JSON to the client to update it's display during the long process run.  Again, this all works perfectly and I've never seen a gateway timeout on this particular connect.

My problem is when I open another tab in my browser and try and do something else in my PHP program while the import process is running.  It is these subsequent connections that hang and eventually return the "504 gateway timeout".  If it's an entirely different PHP project, it appears to work so it is only when the same 'index.php' script is being executed.

The kicker is, if I grab my android tablet and pull up a page there it works fine.

So it would appear that PHP-FPM is only allow a single script execution per client.

What.... the....?

I actually have the same set up on 3 machines and they all do the same thing.  Anyone know what I've done to botch this up?

Thanks.

Comment: sessions? what if you open in a different browser or in incognito?

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere.  Yes, opening and incognito works!  I'm still not sure where the problem is or how to fix it though.

Comment: Well, sessions? :-D Do those apps share sessions?

Comment: Just found this.  http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/solving-concurrent-request-blocking-in-php which explains everything.  I was not aware that sessions blocked like that.  Must be my caching backend which uses sessions to store data.  Might switch it over to memcached or something and see if that fixes it.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, I never directly access the $_SESSION variable and instead use my Session class.  So at the end of the constructor I called session_write_close() to fix it.  Also, overall app responsiveness has increased considerably.  Much win!